# Probability theory - Logic, Notation, simulation

Tags: probability, statistics, notation, conditional-probability

i need some help in probability theory. The thing is im not sure if im thinking about this correctly and if i express my thoughts correctly. I really got lost in all the dice examples of the internet.

Let $\ X\ \in \{1,0\} $ a binary outcome. Eg. missing the train in the morning, or not.

Let $\ p\ $be the probability of missing the train. 
$$
P(X=1) = p
$$
$$
P(X=0) = 1-p
$$
Lets say we use the train $\ n$ times, where each event is independent and identically distributed.
Then im pretty sure that the probability of missing the train ***at least 1 time*** is:
$$
1-[(1-p)^n]
$$
What is the correct notation for this Probability? This cant be correct:
$$
P(X>=1 |\ n\ )
$$
What about the probability of missing the train ***exactly one time*** in $n$ events?
I would guess its just
$$
P(X=1|\ n \ ) = (1-p)^n \ * \ p
$$
Also is the notation correct here?

Now how can i answer this question :
*"For which n there is a 100% probability of missing the train?"* and should i use P("at least one time" | n ) or P("exactly one time" | n ) to answer this question ?

Besides the questions above i have one more (less important) question : Is there some kind of distribution which describes this case, given $(p, n)$ and how to simulate a process like this in general. I am using numpy and python.

Comment: Not sure there's a universally accepted notation for that, I'd just spell it out.  Also, your formula for "exactly one time" is wrong.  Hint; the unique occurrence could be in any of the $n$ positions.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE!  Your question *isn't* realated to Kolmogorov's axiomatic probability, so I've [edit]ed the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You need a random variable for the number $Y$ of missed trains in $n$ trips. Then the usual notations, and correct computations, would be $$P(Y \ge 1) = 1- P(Y = 0) = 1-(1-p)^n, \\P(Y = 1) = {n \choose 1}p^1(1-p)^{n-1}=
np(1-p)^{n-1},$$ and so on.

Comment: @Henry. Thanks for fixing typo.

Answer (score 1):

If $X_i$ are indicators of missing the train on each occasion, you could say $$\mathbb P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \ge 1\right) = 1-(1-p)^n$$ for the probability of missing at least once, and $$\mathbb P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i = 1\right) = np(1-p)^{n-1}$$ for the probability of missing exactly once

As BruceET says, this might look simpler if you define $Y=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$, in which case $Y$ has a [binomial distribution](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.binomial.html) with parameters $n$ and $p$